# What is bottom-up pattern matching?

Tags: parsers

On [the website for the book *Modern Compiler Design*](https://dickgrune.com/Books/MCD_2nd_Edition/), it is claimed that:

> [The book] recognizes lexical analysis, LR parsing and BURS code generation as
> instances of bottom-up pattern matching and explains them uniformly
> using dotted items, thus unifying three important techniques in
> compiler design, [...]

([BURS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BURS) seems to stand for *bottom-up rewrite system*.)

**I would like to know what *bottom-up pattern matching* is**, but searching for that term did not give me too many results. One result is about *bottom-up tree pattern matching*, but it is unclear to me whether this is the same thing or not.

Answer (score 1):

Matching is the same activity for regular expressions (and variants of them) as parsing is for grammars.

Top-down matching/parsing tries to expand parse trees for the input from the root downwards. Standard examples in compiler construction courses are *recursive descent* and *LL(k) parsing*.

With top-down parsing, while scanning the input, you maintain a single valid parse tree for the input up to that point.

With recursive descent, as soon as your parse is failing, you recursively back up and try the next alternative, until the parse is complete or all alternatives have been exhausted. This is guaranteed to produce a valid parse if one exists, but it may take exponential time in the length of the input.

If the grammar is LL(k), it guarantees that whenever multiple alternatives exist for continuing the parse, you can always decide which one to use by looking ahead no more than k characters in the input. So you'll never have to back up, and parsing can be done in linear time - provided you have an LL(k) grammar, which not all languages have.

Bottom-up matching/parsing tries to assemble parse trees from the leaves upwards.  Standard examples in compiler construction courses are *Earley parsing*, *GLR parsing*, and *LR(k) parsing*.

With bottom-up parsing, while scanning the input, you maintain a representation of all valid partial parse trees for the input up to that point. So you'll never back up; instead, you construct all valid partial parse trees in parallel. While their total number can be exponential, for context-free grammars they can be represented and constructed in polynomial (cubic) time.  Earley parsing, GLR parsing, and its variants make this work for arbitrary context-free grammars; LR(k) parsing is a less general method that, again, uses lookahead to always reduce the number of partial parses to consider to at most one, and only works for LR(k) grammars, which, again, not all languages have.

I can't find any examples of bottom-up matching directly on regular expressions; the custom is to convert them to nondeterministic or even deterministic automata and use those to do the matching.

Comment: @reinerpost: In the author's view, a FSA is a bottom-up matcher; each state corresponds to the position of the dot in an itemset, much as in an LR parser. This avoids rescanning (within a token). The top-down equivalent, which is common in regex-library-based implementations (eg. in Python or JS), is to try a set of regular expressions one at a time, which leverages native regex support but may rescan tokens several times, particular if trying to implement maximal munch.

Comment: But the most interesting part of the text is precisely about bottom-up tree matching, used in a number of code-generation algorithms. Unifying the discussion of the different bottom-up techniques probably helps the student understand the utility of this approach.

Comment: @rici: I'm wondering if any direct bottom-up matching algorithms have been published (using item sets consisting of dotted regular expressions or some such thing). It probably boils down to the same thing as using the FSA, I never tried it.

Comment: There's a lexical analysis algorithm in Grune's book, described in those terms.